# Make text appear in a textbox when clicking on button

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, linkbutton

I have some text which I want to appear in a textbox which I click on the linkbutton "Edit"
As you can see I have `CommandNames` and `CommandArguments` on those linkbuttons so I need a solution which can be written in the codebehind (.cs) as I got an `if (e.CommandName == "Edit")`

I haven't tried anything, as I can't find anything about it, neither in my head.

### Designer Code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
    <asp:ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Text" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Save" runat="server" CommandName="Save" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'> Save </asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'> Edit </asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton_Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'> Delete </asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </asp:ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource_Forside" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table1]"> <asp:SqlDataSource>
```

### Code behind:

```
if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM Table1 WHERE Id = @Id";


        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            TextBox_Edit.Text = reader["Text"].ToString(); // i dont have the textbox yet..
        }
        conn.Close();

        Repeater1.DataBind();

    }
```

Comment: I don't get it, which textbox? What text? why?

Comment: @ArcaneSwift: did any of the following work ?

Comment: The text is this one <%# Eval("Text") %> the text is in the database/table whatever and yet its "bla bla" and when you click on the edit button, there should appear a textbox, instead of the text, so you can edit in that, the textbox should appear in the same place, like "overwrite" the normal text but the text should still be in the textbox.. and then you can edit it and click save and the new text is saved and the textbox disappear and then the normal text get back?

Hope you understand, im not the best at English grammar :D

Comment: Yes But you have to use grid view for that ? Are you using Grid view ?
Or did the below answer work ?...We understood what you want.

Comment: The only thing im using is Table.

Comment: I dont see why i should use a TemplateField and EditItemTemplate, as i dont use gridview.

Comment: Else you have create a control textbox and on edit attached it to the first row and place the value of text in it.

Comment: You do have the textbox in place right now, correct ?

Comment: Its right below the normal text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you have to do:

```
if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM Table1 WHERE Id = @Id";


    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    TextBox_Text.Text=reader["Text"].ToString();;

    conn.Close();

    Repeater1.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: I dont see why i should use TemplateField, EditItemTemplate
I have all the markup, i just need the textbox to "overwrite" the text so it can be edited, instead of having a textbox appear in the bottom.

Comment: Because the TemplateField allows you to display EditTemplate when you click "edit" button. Thus, the text will appear in Textbox.

Comment: What does that have to do with codebehind ? Can't you edit the code in aspx file ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use DataGridView using OnRowCommand.. something like this:

```
protected void GridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
           id = Convert.ToInt32(gridName.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)]["id_DataKey"].ToString());
           TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtBoxName");
           txt.Text = "Removed";
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you use that when i dont use a gridview?